# Set (featured) thumbnail for post?

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

I'm using wp_insert_post and media_sideload_image to create a post and attach a single image to the post. However, how can I mark this attached image as featured thumbnail? It would make listing the thumbnails significantly faster by using the_post_thumbnail instead of looping through each post manually showing the first image.

How can I mark the attached image as featured thumbnail?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use `set_post_thumbnail()`? ([Codex ref.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail))

**EDIT**

To get the attachment ID using the Post ID:

```
// Associative array of attachments, as $attachment_id => $attachment
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

$attachment = $attachments[0]; // ID of your single, attached image.
```

Then to set it as the featured image:

```
set_post_thumbnail( $attachment );
```

I have to check to be sure; the docs are a bit confusing. The default output might be an object. Regardless, `get_children()` will get you to the ID of your lone attachment, given the Post ID.

Comment: Hi Chip, excellent choice, but I've been so far unable to find the actual attachment or thumbnail ID of the image, any idea on how to get it?

Comment: Do you have the ID of the Post?

Comment: Yup, I sure do :)

Comment: See updated answer. :)

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work, as the array number is not 0 but the actual ID of the attachment: attachmentID: Array
(
    [266] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 266
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2011-06-23 11:44:18
            [post_date_gmt] => 2011-06-23 09:44:18
In other words, I need to find a way to get this ID in order to properly parse it.

Comment: got it; changed it to current($attachments)->ID.  Thanks!